# Why are HashTable order different in Visual Studio Debugging compared to IIS

Tags: c#, hashtable

I have a very curious thing happening in my application with HashTables.

First off: Yes, I know that HashTables are not supposed to be ordered in the way the were inserted, or any other way (but the hashes of the keys). That doesn't answer my question. I do not need it ordered, I just want to know WHY it differs between two seemingly identical systems.

So, here it is. Left side is IIS ordering, right side is Visual Studio.

[image: IIS vs VS ordering in HashTable]

Why is it different? Considering that .NET should (?) use the same algorithm to store, and retreive, data from a HashTable, the ordering should be the same on both sides, shouldn't it?

If, as I learned it, the key of a HashTable is hashed, then this hash should be the same on both systems, resulting in the same order of hashes (keys) and therefore the same order of data in the hashtable.

Where am I wrong? What difference is there in the HashTable implementation between IIS and VS?

A few extra notes from comments:

- Project is targeted at .NET 4.0
- IIS uses .NET 4.0 for the Application Pool
- I actually copied the compiled binaries from Visual Studios `bin` folder to the IIS folder, so they are exactly the same
- My assumption is that IIS uses the same .NET implementation as Visual Studio. If not: Why? And what makes the hashing on IIS so different from the one in Visual Studio?

Comment: "the ordering should be the same" depends on the implementation so the framework. It also depends on whether or not you've already removed items.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The algorithms state at the time the screen was taken was exactly the same on both sides. Also, as it was on the same machine, I assumed that the IIS uses the same .NET implementation as Visual Studio (which is a fair assumption?)

Comment: The IIS can use whatever .NET version is configured for that application pool. Visual Studio can run whatever you have configured as target-framework.

Comment: Well, I used v4.0x64 for both - why would the implementation differ?

Comment: Even the same code (function) shouldn't produce the same result on multiple execution (think about deterministic and non-deterministic function). In another hand hash function is deterministic but how do you collect your table and log to the file? That process can be non deterministic (think about parallelism).

Comment: @HamletHakobyan The logging is consistent with a bug that I fixed whose underlying reason was the fact that on IIS, the first entry in the HashTable was a different one than that on my local machine. Yes, the logging shown here might not be exact, but it illustrates the point anyhow.

Comment: They recently added a feature to scramble hash codes so that attackers can't easily force lots of hash collisions leading to a DOS situation. Search the BCL for an internal method named something like "MarvinsHashCode"...

Comment: "resulting in the same order of hashes (keys) and therefore the same order of data in the hashtable." - please correct me if I'm wrong but isn't Hashtable and its enumerator not ordered in any specific way (including hashes)?

Comment: @S_F The iterator has to have the same order always, otherwise the function would be non-deterministic, which I really really don't believe it is (see what Hamlet wrote)

Comment: To get rid your doubts about difference between VS and IIS try run same code in VS multiple times and compare results.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Already done before posting. The order in VS is always the same, and the order in IIS is also always the same in every iteration. But compared, they are different between the two systems

Comment: @usr I tried searching, but could not come up with something. Do you have more information?

Comment: @FlorianPeschka it's InternalMarvin32HashString and the UseRandomizedStringHashAlgorithm config element. That's all I know.

Comment: @usr I found it, thanks for the hints. Now all that is missing is finding the config file where this is actually configured. I can't seem to find it anywhere in the IIS or Application configs...

Comment: @FlorianPeschka I suspect there is a reason that the configuration is obtained in unmanaged code. Normally, the string class could just read the config from the app.config but it does not. There must be a reason. There must be some further logic, maybe it depends on the CLR host.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka https://github.com/floodyberry/Marvin32/blob/master/Marvin32.c that's the algorithm. This does not answer where the seed comes from, though, and what causes the algorithm to be used.

Comment: @usr Can you add all this to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @FlorianPeschka thanks, but I'm not interested. I don't think that's good enough as an answer I'd want my name under. We really didn't find out much :)

Comment: @usr Okay, well... It's good enough for me. I will add it on my own when no one else bothers to. What you pointed out is very insightful, it would be a shame to let it g to waste in hidden comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @usr helped me find out, the reason for this behaviour lies in the [GetHashCode()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,0a17bbac4851d0d4) function, which is used as the base for the `HashTable`s keys. Depending on the key, the order of Iteration over a `HashTable` will be different.

A hash function should normally return the same hash vor every input, **but**... this function returns different hashes, depending on a configuration parameter, namely [<UseRandomizedStringHashAlgorithm>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152924.aspx) which will return a different hash, created by a mysterious function [InternalMarvin32HashString()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,501774d5676172e1).

It was introduced to prevent a *Hash Flooding* DOS attack vector.

This function however

> [...] is imported from an external DLL, clr.dll to be precise.

*from [Martin Boßlet Dec 14th, 2012](http://emboss.github.io/blog/2012/12/14/breaking-murmur-hash-flooding-dos-reloaded/)*

So we cannot really know, what it does exactly without some major (maybe even illegal) refactoring going on.

Answer (score 4):

In order for items in the table to have the same ordering several conditions must be met:

1. Hash algorithm must be the same. This means not only the hash function, but also the way the table grows, shrinks, handles collision, and so on. This is probably the reason in your case (different algorithms).
2. Environment must be the same. Makes sense if one of the parameters of hash algorithm is something from the environment, like available memory. Some algorithms are pretty sophisticated, trying to avoid page misses or spicing the table for security purposes.
3. Data must be the same, and stored in hash table in the same order.

Comment: This answers it theoretically. I was hoping to find some hard evidence on what exactly (1) and (2) are. (3) is the same for sure, I confirmed that.

Comment: @Florian, sorry, I thought you asked "why the difference", not "what is the difference". Answer to that would require pretty specific, maybe even insider knowledge.

Comment: "Makes sense if one of the parameters of hash algorithm is something from the environment, like available memory" this can't be true.  The hash algorithm is deterministic.

Comment: @Dialecticus Okay, maybe I should write that more clear in the question. I am aware that this can probably not be answered, but I also wanted to have this effect/issue documented somewhere, with or without answers.

Comment: @Hamlet, "deterministic" means that same input cannot produce different output (or even different internal state), but environment can be part of the input.

Comment: @Dialecticus, of course. So "something from the environment, like available memory" doesn't matter.

Comment: To me it's obvious that it could matter, and also puzzling that it is not obvious to you. Like I said, environment can be part of the input. Let's just agree to disagree.

Comment: "but environment can be part of the input" No. The input can be only the data which will be hashed.

Comment: Well, it seems that is only half-right in the special case of the IIS. Taking a look at the hints about `InternalMarvin32HashString` reveals some information that there is something more than just input used when `UseRandomizedStringHashAlgorithm` is activated for an IIS... More readings: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152924.aspx), [here](http://emboss.github.io/blog/2012/12/14/breaking-murmur-hash-flooding-dos-reloaded/) and [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,0a17bbac4851d0d4)